# partial derivative transformation rule

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, tangent-spaces

If $\phi$ is a map between coordinates given by
$$
\xi=\xi(x,y)\\
\eta=\eta(x,y)\\
$$
with inverse $\phi^{-1}$
$$
x=x(\xi,\eta)\\
y=y(\xi,\eta)\\
$$
the transformation rule for partial derivatives are
$$
\partial_\xi=\partial_\xi x\partial_x+\partial_\xi y\partial_y\\
\partial_\eta=\partial_\eta x\partial_x+\partial_\eta y\partial_y
$$
and
$$
\partial_x=\partial_x \xi\partial_\xi+\partial_x \eta\partial_\eta\\
\partial_y=\partial_y \xi\partial_\xi+\partial_y \eta\partial_\eta.\\
$$
now my perplexity is the following: can I put one set of equation inside the other? It is possible to write
$$
\partial_\xi=A\partial_\xi+B\partial_\eta\\
\partial_\eta=C\partial_\xi+D\partial_\eta\\
$$
and it seems that the combination of partial derivative must obey the following conditions $A=1$, $B=0$, $C=0$ and $D=1$. Is it true?

Comment: yes that's right, $A=D=1$ and $B=C=0$. One way of seeing this is that when you express $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, you use the chain rule for $\phi^{-1}$. SImilarly, when expressing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}$, one is applying the chain rule to $\phi$. So, if you plug one set of equations into another, you're just applying the chain rule to $\phi^{-1}\circ \phi=\text{id}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just for clarity, we'll use the $\cdot$-symbol to distinguish multiplication from a partial derivation operation.)

As peek-a-boo commented, we should anticipate that $\partial_\xi=1\cdot\partial_\xi+0\cdot\partial_\eta$ or else something is seriously awry.

So is this what happens?

$\begin{align}\partial_\xi &= \partial_\xi x\cdot\partial_x + \partial_\xi y\cdot\partial_y&&\text{chain rule}\\&=\partial_\xi x\cdot(\partial _x\xi\cdot\partial_\xi+\partial_x\eta\cdot\partial_\eta)+\partial_\xi y\cdot(\partial _y\xi\cdot\partial_\xi+\partial_y\eta\cdot\partial_\eta)&&\text{chain rule}\times 2\\&=(\partial_\xi x\cdot\partial_x\xi+\partial_\xi y\cdot\partial _y\xi)\cdot\partial_\xi+(\partial_\xi x\cdot\partial_x\eta+\partial_\xi y\cdot\partial _y\eta)\cdot\partial_\eta&&\text{multiplication distributes, commutes & associates}\\&=[\partial_\xi x\cdot\partial_x+\partial_\xi y\cdot\partial_y]\xi\cdot\partial_\xi +[\partial_\xi x\cdot\partial_x+\partial_\xi y\cdot\partial_y]\eta\cdot\partial_\eta&&\text{linear operation distributes}\\&=\partial_\xi\xi\cdot\partial_\xi+\partial_\xi\eta\cdot\partial_\eta&&\text{chain rule}\times 2\\&=1\cdot\partial_\xi+0\cdot\partial_\eta&&\text{partial differentiation, by definition}\\&=\partial_\xi&&\text{... as it should}\end{align}$

What a relief.